# Add Heading to a group of columns in Oracle SQL

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

Oracle 11g. Oracle Apex 5.1

I need to Merge the columns without merging the data and Add a column heading in Oracle Apex Interactive Report.

For Example
I have a table like this:
[image]

I want the table output like this:
[image]

How can I achieve the output in Report Select Statement?
If I am using below query in Oracle Apex Interactive Report:

```
TITLE LEFT '    amount_column       Quantity_column'
SELECT Date, Amount1, Amount2, Amount3, Quantity1, Quantity2
FROM   table_name;
```

I am getting error as: ORA-20001: Query must begin with SELECT or WITH.

Comment: You can't have a different number of columns from different rows in a query. Unless you're generating the output as HTML, I don't think this is possible. This is something your presentation layer should be doing, not the database.

Answer (score 1):

In oracle Apex 5.1 we can create such groups in Interactive Grid(IG).
To create a group, steps are:
Go to Attribute of IG -> create Group -> add a name to group.

To assign a group on column, steps are:
go to particular column(s) name -> under layout property -> select group name

Save and run the page and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running the query to get a SQL/Plus style textual output (using <kbd>Crtl-F5</kbd> / run-as-script within SQL Developer) then you can use the commands for [formatting SQL*Plus reports](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14357/ch6.htm) such as [`COLUMN`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14357/ch12013.htm#BACHCABF) and [`TTITLE`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14357/ch12048.htm) to make it appear like your desired result:

Something like (untested):

```
COLUMN "Date"    FORMAT A9
COLUMN Amount1   FORMAT 9999.99
COLUMN Amount2   FORMAT 9999.99
COLUMN Amount3   FORMAT 9999.99
COLUMN Quantity1 FORMAT 999999999
COLUMN Quantity2 FORMAT 999999999
TTITLE LEFT '              Amount column       Quantity Column'
SELECT "Date", Amount1, Amount2, Amount3, Quantity1, Quantity2
FROM   table_name;
```

If you want to do it in the grid (using <kbd>F5</kbd> to run the query within SQL Developer) then you are out of luck and it is not possible.

Comment: you're not out of luck, just in the wrong presentation layer - build your report in APEX

Comment: I have fixed this in Oracle Apex. Thanks. :)

Comment: @ParulJ If you have a solution to your question then you can post it as an answer (and accept it) so that other people can also benefit from the solution.